# Enable ScrollView When Keyboard Appears

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView with a UINavigation controller and several other Imageviews and a text filed inside it. On the Nagivation bar there is a UIBarbutton item which pushes another ViewController.

When the text field in the Navigation Viewcontroller is tapped it brings up the keyboard causing the Navigation bar with UIBarbutton item to slide out of the screen and thus making the UIBarbutton item unaccessible until the done button is pressed on the keyboard.

A notification is sent to this method whenever the keyboard is invoked.

```
- (void)displayKeyboard {


self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, 0.0, -100.0);
}
```

I tried using the IB to add a scrollview onto the view but this causes the entire view to be blocked.

Is there any other way i can enable the scroll view whenever the keyboard appears so i can scoll the entire screen ?

Comment: So you want to scroll when the keyboard is visible and not scroll, when it is hidden? What's wrong with `scrollView.enabled = YES;` in the methods called when the keyboard is shown?

Comment: tried that already doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try setting the frame of the current view.. for example:

```
CGRect r = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(r.origin.x, r.origin.y, r.size.width, r.size.height-100);
```

and when the user done with the keyboard, add 100 to bring it back.... (instead of 100, you should get the value from the notification object that contains the height, position of the keyboard)...

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I have implemented this as well although it works the issue with this is that it covers up my text field the when the keyboards appears.

Comment: if you had scrollview... then you could set the contentOffset.. that way you can scroll the view up so textfield is above the keyboard...